# Laravel Passport Login Auth Failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I tried to login with postman.And i got this error message when post username and password to localhost/api/login.

```
    {
    "error": "invalid_credentials",
    "message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
    }
```

My LoginController

```
private $client;

public function __construct(){
    $this->client = Client::find(1);
}

public function login(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    return $this->issueToken($request, 'password');
}
```

And my issueToken method.

```
public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = ""){

    $params = [
        'grant_type' => $grantType,
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,           
        'scope' => $scope
    ];

    if($grantType !== 'social'){
        $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;
    }

    $request->request->add($params);

    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

    return Route::dispatch($proxy);

}
```

My register event works fine.So what is my false?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
if($grantType !== 'social'){
   $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;
   $params['password'] = $request->password; //Send password too ?
}
```

Comment: No.Because if i debug the code,issueToken() method did not run.I mean i got this error before the methods run.

Comment: If you add dd($request) or return something in the start of the function it doesnt run? Both of them are in the same controller right?

Comment: If i add dd($request) i got some values which i don't understand.Check this https://jsfiddle.net/ef6mmm1z/